# How to enlarge font size of INCOMING main in IBM Notes 9

Tags: lotus-notes

All the obvious font adjustments in Notes only affect outgoing mail. How can I increase the size of fonts for INCOMING mail?

Answer (score 1):

Incoming font sizes are determined by the sender when viewing in anything other than text only modes. This is how most email applications work.

This is because HTML and Rich Text email types behave like documents, where the person creating the document gets to decide the layout, size, color, and other aspects of the elements of the email.

Your only option to make the text in incoming emails larger is to use whichever Zoom controls the client offers, or to use the Scaling options available in the Operating System.

Comment: Thanks music2myear, I was afraid that was the case. I don't want to change scaling as that would affect everything, not just Notes. I can always just use the web version of Notes (IBM Verse), I just prefer the traditional Notes interface. sigh